# Aeroo Reports Error : "File is not a zip file" when modifying with libreoffice

Tags: reporting, openerp-7

I was happily using a custom invoice aeroo report, when I've lost the hability to change the report.
If I open the invoice template, modify any field and save with libreoffice and replacing the odt in the module, then the OpenERP says:

```
File is not a zip file

(<class 'zipfile.BadZipfile'>, BadZipfile('File is not a zip file',), <traceback object at 0x7f2910b6e0e0>)
```

I don't know how to debug this message. In openerp-server.log is not saying nothing about the error. Any clues how to solve this?

Thanks in advance,

PS: OpenERP 7.0, aeroo Reports for OERP7, ubuntu 12.04, LibreOffice 4.1.4.2

Comment: Check in your module weather any zip file available or not if yes than remove it. And than upgrade all aeroo report modules from GUI.

Comment: I've checked this, and done the upgrade too without any change BUT. I've seen that I was trying to retrieve a empty field with the a invoice without that field. Now is working well with invoice because this field always is not null. I supose that the error message is a generic one and the problem was this null field. I'll keep searching for more tests...but for now it will do. Thanks.

Comment: Ohk. Good. Than you can write answer below so other will notified and you can accept your own answer also. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that this error message is a generic one.

Reason:I've find a field in my report that was null and I haven't set a test to null in the report. Now my report always return something on that field and the template is working well.

As for now, I'll assume this question answered.